# Error and Dispersion meaning in tune.out for SVM Classifier

Tags: cross-validation, svm, e1071

I am using a *SVM* to solve a binary classification problem with qualitative response as output.

To find out the best parameters for the SVM I used a *10-fold cross-validation* technique. And the result of the process was (under *RStudio* and *R*):

```
Parameter tuning of ‘svm’:

- sampling method: 10-fold cross validation 

- best parameters:
 cost
    5

- best performance: 0.25 

- Detailed performance results:
   cost     error dispersion
1 1e-03 0.4833333  0.2415229
2 1e-02 0.4833333  0.2415229
3 1e-01 0.3500000  0.1657382
4 1e+00 0.2666667  0.1405457
5 5e+00 0.2500000  0.1416394
6 1e+01 0.2666667  0.1791613
7 1e+02 0.2666667  0.1791613
```

What I am asking to myself is what are the error and dispersion, and how are they calculated?

I tried to answer: Is the error the average MSE of the ten estimates of the test errors? I think not because the classification problem has a qualitative response, and the CV-error-rate should be calculated on misclassified observations.

I am bit confused about this.

Comment: *Error* is close to you might intuitively expect it to be: the proportion of the validation examples (averaged or summed over the ten folds) which are misclassified when using that particular hyperparameter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you dig into the code of `tune`, you'll find that it calculates error for each of the surrogate models, and then aggregates these per-model error estimates into a point estimate (that is reported in your summary as error) and dispersion.

- For classification, the surrogate-model error estimate is fraction of correctly predicted among all predictions = accuracy.
- the aggregation function for the point estimate is `tunecontrol$sampling.aggregate` which defaults to `mean`,
- the aggregation function for the dispersion is `tunecontrol$sampling.dispersion`, defaulting to `sd`.

See also the man page of `tune.control()`.